# Updating an array of objects with a new key in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, insert, updates

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209670/mongo-push-to-array-inside-array)

Barrowing the data set, I have something similar to this:

```
{
    'user_id':'{1231mjnD-32JIjn-3213}',
    'name':'John',
    'campaigns':
        [
            {
                'campaign_id':3221,
                'start_date':'12-01-2012',
            },
            {
                'campaign_id':3222,
                'start_date':'13-01-2012',
            }
        ]
}
```

And I want to add a new key in the `campaigns` like so:

```
{
    'user_id':'{1231mjnD-32JIjn-3213}',
    'name':'John',
    'campaigns':
        [
            {
                'campaign_id':3221,
                'start_date':'12-01-2012',
                'worker_id': '00000'
            },
            {
                'campaign_id':3222,
                'start_date':'13-01-2012',
                'worker_id': '00000'
            }
        ]
}
```

How to `insert/update` a new key into an array of objects?
I want to add a new key into every object inside the array with a default value of `00000`.

I have tried:
 `db.test.update({}, {$set: {'campaigns.worker_id': 00000}}, true, true)`
 `db.test.update({}, {$set: {campaigns: {worker_id': 00000}}}, true, true)`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm supposing that this operation will occur once, so you can use a script to handle it:

```
var docs = db.test.find();
for(var i in docs) {
    var document = docs[i];

    for(var j in document.campaigns) {
        var campaign = document.campaigns[j];
        campaign.worker_id = '00000';
    }

    db.test.save(document);
}
```

The script will iterate over all documents in your collection then over all campaigns in each document, setting the *worker_id* property.
At the end, each document is persisted.

Comment: I put the code into a file called `addTo.js`.  Then in the mongo shell I have `mongo addTo.js`.  The error follows: `InternalError: too much recursion src/mongo/shell/collection.js:131`.  Is this the correct way?

Comment: How much documents you have in this collection? Maybe you should run the script many times, using skip and limit function to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.test.update({}, {$set: {'campaigns.0.worker_id': 00000}}, true, true
```

this will update 0 element.

if you want to `add a new key into every object inside the array` you should use:
`$unwind`

example:

```
{
  title : "this is my title" ,
  author : "bob" ,
  posted : new Date() ,
  pageViews : 5 ,
  tags : [ "fun" , "good" , "fun" ] ,
  comments : [
      { author :"joe" , text : "this is cool" } ,
      { author :"sam" , text : "this is bad" }
  ],
  other : { foo : 5 }
}
```

unwinding tags

```
db.article.aggregate(
    { $project : {
        author : 1 ,
        title : 1 ,
        tags : 1
    }},
    { $unwind : "$tags" }
);
```

result:

```
{
     "result" : [
             {
                     "_id" : ObjectId("4e6e4ef557b77501a49233f6"),
                     "title" : "this is my title",
                     "author" : "bob",
                     "tags" : "fun"
             },
             {
                     "_id" : ObjectId("4e6e4ef557b77501a49233f6"),
                     "title" : "this is my title",
                     "author" : "bob",
                     "tags" : "good"
             },
             {
                     "_id" : ObjectId("4e6e4ef557b77501a49233f6"),
                     "title" : "this is my title",
                     "author" : "bob",
                     "tags" : "fun"
             }
     ],
     "OK" : 1
}
```

After you could write simple updaiting query.

Comment: Adding a new key must be done through a script and not through the mongo shell?

Comment: If you can do it through mongo shell that means you can use it through each mongo driver.

Comment: Can you do it through the mongo shell?  As far as I know `aggregate` doesn't modify the database but outputs a document that is requested.  I want to modify the actual db.

Comment: it's just example. i had want to get you a point for solving your problem. http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html

Comment: I understand and thank you but I was looking for something that modifies the document through the mongo shell.  I am sure this problem is solvable applying a script but I would like to use the mongo shell directly.

Comment: You may solve be use mongo shell directly. What you did't understood?