# How do you push to an array inside of an object, inside of an array with MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, backend

I need to be able to push new objects to `fameTotals`. Having a bit of trouble, thanks!

This is what the document would look like in my database:

```js
{
  clanName: null,
  clanTag: null,
  players: [
    {
      name: null,
      tag: null,
      fameTotals: [ //PUSH TO THIS ARRAY
        {fame: 0, clanTrophies: 0, date: ''}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've been trying to figure it out with `updateOne()` and the `$push` operator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209670/mongo-push-to-array-inside-array

Answer (score 0):

Check this example

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
{
  $push: {
    players: {
      name: "yyy",
      tag: "bbbb",
      fameTotals: [
        {
          fame: 1,
          clanTrophies: 1,
          date: "27-7-21"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FEALyZocgQG)